# Web scraping ebay with selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

Hi I am extremely new to coding, and I'm working on a project to scrape data from eBay using selenium.

There are 2 problems I have encountered.

1. The XPath for the listing name is 
   `//*[@id="srp-river-results-listing1"]/div/div[2]/a/h3`
   how can I tell python that i want every listing , that is `listing >=1`?
2. for the xpath of the price of the listing
   `//*[@id="srp-river-results-listing1"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/span`
   is what I directly copy, but when I enter it into python, it says there are invalid syntax and pointing to `div[2]`, the same situation also occurs to the condition of the listing.
   However, for the name, shipping cost, and country of origin, it will work.
   How can I avoid fix these?

Thank you so much, and I am not allowed to use eBay API

Comment: 1. get list with all values and later use Python loop to get only some elements from list.

Comment: 1. `//*[contains(@id, "srp-river-results-listing")]` ?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: 2. maybe it needs to put element in `()` before you use `[]` - ie. `(//*[@id="srp-river-results-listing1"]/div/div)[2]/a/h3`

Comment: I don't know what URL you scrape but on ebay.com I can get names using simple `//h3[@class="s-item__title"]` and prices `//span[@class="s-item__price"]`. And instead of `@id="srp-river-results-listing1` with different numbers in `listing` I can use `//li[@class="s-item   "]`

Answer (score 0):

1) To search by partial name you can use `contains()`

```
'//*[contains(@id, "srp-river-results-listing")]/div/div[2]/a/h3'
```

It can be useful with classes because `xpath` in `Selenium` treats all classes as one string and xpath `@class="s-item__title"` will not find `<div class="s-item__title promotion">`

```
'//h3[contains(@class, "s-item__title")]`
```

You can use it also to search by text displayed on page

```
'//h3[contains(@text, "Raspberry")]`
```

---

2). I don't know what is the problem - you didn't show full error message.

---

BTW: instead of using long xpath you can find the same items using shorter xpath

```
'//h3[contains(@class, "s-item__title")]'
```

and

```
'//span[@class="s-item__price"]'
```

Evetually you can try to use `//` to skip some elements in path

```
'//li[contains(@id, "srp-river-results-listing")]//span'
```

And it may not need `div[2]`

---

Sometimes it is good to find main tag and later search only inside this tag using relative xpath with `.` .

It can be useful to group information about one item. Sometimes items may not have some values and then using `zip(all_titles, all_prices)` to group information may gives wrong results.

```
data = []

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="s-item   "]')

for item in all_items:
    # relative xpathes 

    title = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//h3[contains(@class, "s-item__title")]').text.strip()
    price = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="s-item__price"]').text.strip()

    data.append( [title, price] )
```

---

Example code

```
import selenium.webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2499334.m570.l1311.R1.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.Xras.TRS0&_nkw=raspberry+pi+4&_sacat=0')

# --- separated elements ---

all_titles = []

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h3[@class="s-item__title"]')

for item in all_items:
    title = item.text.strip()
    print('title:', title)
    all_titles.append( title )

all_prices = []

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="s-item__price"]')

for item in all_items:
    price = item.text.strip()
    print('price:', price)
    all_prices.append( price )

data = list(zip(all_titles, all_prices))

all_others = []

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//non_existing_xpath')

for item in all_items:
    other = item.text.strip()
    print('other:', other)
    all_others.append( other )

# all_others will be empty


# --- grouped ---

data = []

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="s-item   "]')

for item in all_items:
    title = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//h3[contains(@class, "s-item__title")]').text.strip()
    price = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="s-item__price"]').text.strip()
    try:
        other = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//non_existing_xpath').text.strip()
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception:', ex)
        other = "" # default value when element doesn't exists.

    print('title:', title)
    print('other:', price)
    print('other:', other)
    print('---')
    data.append( [title, price, other])

# --- other examples ---

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[contains(@id, "srp-river-results-listing")]//span[@class="s-item__price"]')
for item in all_items:
    print(item.text)

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[contains(@id, "listing")]//span[@class="s-item__price"]')
for item in all_items:
    print(item.text)

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "srp-river-results-listing")]/div/div[2]/a/h3')
for item in all_items:
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that actually helped a lot. Especially for the part that ignore the sponsor item. But i can only do that for the item name, for the shipping cost, list format etc, it would lead to unequal number of datafrme. Is there a way that i can modify it ?

Comment: some product may not have some tags and you can get unequal number of items if you get every value separatelly - ie. only pices, only titles. And this is why I show second part of code - `grouped`. First it gets `s-item` and later inside `s-item` it search `price` and `title` so I can group them. And if eelemnt doesn't exist in some product then it will not skip it but it will raise error.

Comment: I changed example code. In first part it searchs only all `'//non_existing_xpath'` and it creates empty list. In second part it search single `'.//non_existing_xpath'` inside every product so it raises error and using `try/execpt` I can catch it and put some default value (ie. empty string)